# BotFramework Register a Bot Form Error

Tags: botframework

I get this following error on the form while registering a new Bot.

Error converting value {null} to type 'System.Int32'. Path 'value[0].subscriptionsLimit', line 1, position 203.

https://dev.botframework.com/bots/new  on this page.

What am I doing wrong? I filled all the mandatory fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same issue and had reported it on github (see https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/550).  It was a bug and MS has resolved it; try again now.  I was able to register my bot.